Compare 2 dates to determine same month in Postgresql
I have two dates and I need to check that these two dates are within the same month of the same year.
I have the following solution
select to_char(:date1::date, 'yyyymm')::int2 = to_char(:date2::date, 'yyyymm')::int2

who has a better solution?

What does "better" mean?

Try date_trunc('month',dt1)=date_trunc('month',dt2)

Please [edit] your question to clarify whether it should be the same month of the same year.

how about using date_trunc() which compares month year:
SELECT date_trunc('month',date1) = date_trunc('month',date2)

and if you only need the same month regardless of year you can use date_part:
SELECT date_part('month',date1) = date_part('month',date2)


in this case it may not work
SELECT date_trunc('month','2024-05-02'::Date) = date_trunc('month','2023-05-15'::date)

@Alisherbek oh so you don't care about year , see updated answer

There are different ways to do this. Below are few of them depending on does the month should be within the same year or not.
--    S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table tbl ( id Int, date_1 Date, date_2 Date );
Insert Into tbl VALUES ( 1, '2022-01-01', '2022-01-31' ),
                       ( 2, '2022-01-01', '2023-01-31' ),
                       ( 3, '2024-01-01', '2024-03-31' );

1. same month - same year
Select   *
From     tbl
Where    To_Char(date_1, 'yyyymm') = To_Char(date_2, 'yyyymm')

Select   *
From     tbl
Where    Date_Trunc('Month', date_1) = Date_Trunc('Month', date_2)

Select   *
From     tbl
Where    Extract(YEAR From date_1) = Extract(YEAR From date_2) And 
         Extract(MONTH From date_1) = Extract(MONTH From date_2)

Select   *
From     tbl
Where    DATE_PART('YEAR', date_1) = DATE_PART('YEAR', date_2) And
         DATE_PART('MONTH', date_1) = DATE_PART('MONTH', date_2) 

/*    R e s u l t :   (1)
id  date_1      date_2
--  ----------  ----------
 1  2022-01-01  2022-01-31    */

2. same month - any year
Select   *
From     tbl
Where    To_Char(date_1, 'mm') = To_Char(date_2, 'mm')

Select   *
From     tbl
Where    Extract(MONTH From date_1) = Extract(MONTH From date_2) 

Select   *
From     tbl
Where    DATE_PART('MONTH', date_1) = DATE_PART('MONTH', date_2) 

/*    R e s u l t :   (2)
id  date_1      date_2
--  ----------  ----------
 1  2022-01-01  2022-01-31
 2  2022-01-01  2023-01-31    */

See the fiddle here.
